# Will there be support for static infix notation in scala 3.0?

Tags: scala, infix-notation, dotty, scala-3

When looking at Dotty's (Scala 3.0) [operator rules](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/operators.html), I noticed the following example of the `@alpha` annotation:

```
object VecOps {
  @alpha("append") def (xs: Vec[T]) ++= [T] (ys: Vec[T]): Vec[T] = ...
}
```

This example is meant to illustrate how you can explicitly set the name that a method will be compiled to when it has characters disallowed by java, but it also seems to indicate a new way of defining static infix methods, which as far as I can tell has not been possible to this point.

When I try:

```
object StaticFunctions {
  def (x : Int) myPlus (y: Int) : Int = x + y
}
```

My compiler tells me to get lost.

Is this a new feature? I hope so, because I would love to be able to write static infix functions without resorting to implicit conversions.

If this is a new feature slated for 3.0, why is it not mentioned anywhere in the operator rules section (or anywhere else)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gssh5MBPQd6XZX18r8WwCw. What error does the compiler give?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what "static infix notation" is. Are you talking about [extension methods](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html)? Scala doesn't really have static methods, although I think Dotty does have an `@static` annotation.

Comment: The error I'm getting is: `Error:(5, 9) identifier expected but '(' found. def (x : Int) myPlus (y: Int) : Int = x + y`. By static infix notation, I mean an infix function that is not just a method called on an object ( e.g., `object ExampleObj {  def ** ( i : Int) = i * i }`
`Example Obj ** 5 // evaluates to 25`

Comment: Are you sure you're using Dotty? There's also new syntax for extension methods, you should check it out

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.13, where this notation clearly is not supported. It is clear now that it is supported in Dotty (as your helpful link illustrated). What is confusing, then, is why it is not mentioned anywhere else. At what point did it become possible to define a function as `def ( p1 : A) op (p2 : B) : C = ...`? It is not precisely the same thing as extension methods, which require the keyword "extension", though as far as I can tell they do the same thing...

Comment: It is in fact an extension method, it’s just that tge syntax keeps changing

Comment: I see. Thank you! Great feature to include...